# What is the chance of someone being in a group by a property?

Tags: probability

A set of people is divided to two groups, $A$ and $B$.  Group $A$ has $97\%$ of the people from original set and group $B$ is the other $3\%$.

If $x\%$ of the people in group $A$ have a certain property and $y\%$ of the people of group $B$ have the same property what are the chances that someone with that property is in group $B$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate the number of people in $B$ with that property and divide it by the total number of people with that property:

$$p = {3 \cdot y \over 97 \cdot x + 3 \cdot y}.$$